# input,select and checkbox validation without using form in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am trying to validate the form elements with out enclosing them inside the form tag. I am not able to use the required and ng-pattern inside these elements. I searched this issue and found the jquery validity plugin at this [link](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/Demos/index.htm#) Setup but i need it done in angular. Please help with any ideas and sample codes.

```
<div class="col2" >
<label>Country</label>
<select ng-model="country" ng-options="c for c in countries"><option disabled value = "">Please select an option</option></select>
<label>Language</label>
<select ng-model="language" ng-options="l for l in languages" ><option disabled value = "">Please select an option</option></select>
<label>Currency</label>
<select ng-model="currency" id = "application_currency" ng-options="l for l in currencies"><option disabled value = "">Please select an option</option></select>
</div>

<div class="col2">
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="first" id = "user_firstName"/>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="last" id = "user_lastName"/>
<h3>Default Adjustments</h3>
<div ng-repeat="(i, adj) in adjustments" class="flow">
<input class="col2" type="text" ng-model="adj.name"/>
<input class="col2" type="number" ng-model="adj.value" />
</div>
<button ng-click="addAdjustment()">Additional Field</button> 
</div>

<div class="col2">
<ol>
<li ng-repeat="(line, category) in categories">
  {{line}}
  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat="i in cats"><input type="checkbox"  ng-model="i.checked"/>{{i.name}}</li> 
  </ol>
</li>
</ol>
<button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: which type of validation you want? required?

Comment: please add some code of yours,, that will help me to provide you answer

Comment: i have added the code in the edit.When i press the save button i need it to validate all the fields. thank you @Jatt.net

Comment: Have you tried with 'required'

Comment: yes but its not working.

Comment: but there is not any required seen in your above code

Answer (score 0):

we did this:

html:

```
<input type='text' ng-model='customer.name' ng-class="{false:'has-error', true:'has-success'}[isName]"/>
```

and a validate() function in our controller **before** sending:

```
var isValidCustomer = function (customer) {
    $scope.isName = customer.name.length > 3; // or what ever you want to validate
    return ($scope.isName & otherValidations & forOtherFields);
}
```

the 'has-error' class is a bootstrap class and looks like this:

```
.has-error .form-control {
   border-color: #a94442;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
 }
```

greetings!